# How do I implement a shutdown and restart commands in "on message"?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, replit

My Discord bot runs with discord.py, using the `on_message` function. How do I create commands to shut down, and another to restart Bot?

My bot runs on a server hosted on repl.it.

Code:

```
if message.content.upper().startswith("!SHUTDOWN"):
    if "534116283487223809" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "*Shutting Down...*")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        #SCRIPT TO SHUT DOWN HERE
```

Ideally the commands should respond to `"!shutdown"` and `"!restart"`, and should only be usable by me.

Answer (score 2):

You can place your code in a `while` loop and use [`client.logout()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.logout) to close the Discord connection. The `!restart` command will then only use `client.logout()` without interrupting the `while` loop, and `!shutdown` will also use `client.logout()` but will call `break` to cancel the `while` loop.

You can create commands to handle this instead of having everything in the `on_message` event, which will become cluttered.

```
from discord.ext import commands

while True:
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

    @client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def restart(ctx):
        if "534116283487223809" in [role.id for role in ctx.message.author.roles]:
            await client.logout()

    @client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def shutdown(ctx):
        if "534116283487223809" in [role.id for role in ctx.message.author.roles]:
            await client.logout()
            break

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message)
        # do previous on_message stuff here
        await client.process_commands(message) # add at bottom to allow commands to work

    client.run('token')
```

Comment: I don't understand how `restart` does anything different to `shutdown`. You are talking about some loop, but I see none.

Comment: @Neuron `while True` is an infinite loop that will stop with `break`, which is only present in the `shutdown` command

Comment: Thanks, I missed the line `while True`.. ;)

Answer (score -2):

To exit the script, you would call [`sys.exit([arg])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit). To *restart* the script, take a look at [`os.exec*()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl).

For example:

```
if message.content.upper().startswith("!SHUTDOWN"):
  if "534116283487223809" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "*Shutting Down...*")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.exit(0) # the exit code, 0, means it exited successfully
if message.content.upper().startswith("!RESTART"):
  if "534116283487223809" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "*Restarting...*")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, *sys.argv)
```

Comment: How would I go about adding this to my code? @FlyingSixtySix

Comment: I've added an example. I'm not entirely sure if these will work with repl.it, but it's worth a shot.