# How to make a restart command for my discord.py bot

Tags: discord.py, restart

so far what I've got is:

```
def restart_program():
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)

@bot.command()
async def restart(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("Restarting... Allow up to 5 seconds")
    restart_program()
```

This works, however I'm wondering how I can make it edit the "Restarting... Allow up to 5 seconds" message to say something like "Bot is back up" after it's restarted. Is this possible, and if so, how could I do this?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54540859/how-do-i-implement-a-shutdown-and-restart-commands-in-on-message/54548147#54548147).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `Client.logout()` and `Client.login()` to restart a bot instead of doing it with `os.execl`, but if you really need to do it this way, here is a how you can send a message every time it is started:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    # First get the channel where the message should be sent
    channel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name='general')
    await channel.send("Bot is back up!")
```